# Azure Mobile Engagement for Unity Android

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine

```
EngagementReachAgent.Initialize(); does not exist in the current context
```

How can I solve this error? I can't deliver push notifications and I can't find anywhere a fix for this error. I tried everything that is explained here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-engagement-unity-android-get-started/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not follow the instruction well. You need to download and import the Azure Plugin package into Unity. You can get that [here](https://aka.ms/azmeunitysdk). When this is done, the `EngagementReachAgent` class and the  `Initialize()` function will be present in your Unity project. They are not there now, so you can't use them.